# Ctrl + keys not work on my PHPStorm application

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm for developing my website.

It's works very great.

Recently i got an major problem on this software.

When I use this keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,...

Don't work above key combinations.

also I got this error when using keymaps...

[image]

Please give me a solution...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uninstall **IdeaVim** plug-in in `Settings` | `Plugins` and restart PhpStorm.

Comment: I'm already uninstall this plugin. but , this problem is continue.

Comment: Double check that it's uninstalled and is not disabled. If it doesn't help, rename `C:\Users\<user>\.WebIde50` directory to start with the defaults.

Answer (score 15):

Just go to settings/keymap and choose **default** instead of *Vim*, no need to delete all the settings.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to File -> Setting -> Keymap(In Left Side of the window).
2. Set Keymaps(Drop Down) value to "Default". Done.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with phpstorm but not with other java based IDEs (Intellij worked fine).

If you have dual/multiple keyboard layouts, make sure your first keyboard layout is English. For some reason, having a non en/us layout first, taints jvm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11716

I am using phpstorm-8.0.3 on linux-3.19.0 with gnome-3.14.3 and java-1.8.0_45

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue in WebStorm, where the shortcut keys all of a sudden just stopped working for me.
All I had to do was restart WebStorm. As soon as I started it back up the keyboard shortcuts started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `C:\Users\<user>\.WebIde70\config\keymaps` and delete or rename the Vim.xml file.  If you still have problems after restarting PHPStorm and have any other files in here then do the same with those.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regular behavior like a other code editors, so do this:

1. Go to; File -> Setting -> Keymap(In Left Side of the window).
2. Set Keymaps (Drop Down) value to "Default". Done.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall **IdeaVim**

To remove the configuration files go to ~/.PyChrarm.****(version) and delete this folder, **rm -rf ~/.PyChrarm.****(version)**

Then open Pycharm and config your IDE without **IdeaVim**
This works!!!